# jQuery match elements with .each and delay their processing with setTimeout?

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each

Trying to match elements and fire them off at set intervals with .each(), but can't get the reference to the matched element right.

This matches correctly, but they're all fired at the same time:

```
$("div[id^='data_field'] input:submit").each(function(index) { setTimeout(console.log($(this)),1000*index );  });
```

This fires them correctly, but element matching goes wrong:

```
$("div[id^='data_field'] input:submit").each(function(index) { setTimeout(function(){ console.log($(this)); },1000*index );   });
```

How to get it right? And yes it needs to be with .each...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"this" becomes something else when scoped to the function inside the setTimeout. If you store the information in `$(this)` outside of the setTimeout then it works. Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VZwFB/1/

Comment: Umm i'm sorry i'm a newbie, but i only see my own code in the link..?

Comment: Thank you! That solves...part of the problem :D because in reality i'm trying to .submit or .click the $this. But with $(this).val() it turns out i cannot do that, tried submitVal.submit(); .click(); .onclick(); but they all give error Uncaught TypeError: Object XXX has no method submit?

Comment: try `var submit = $(this);` and then `submit.trigger("click");`

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, that finally solved my problem totally! I have been stumped by this for several days now. If anybody has alternative ways of doing this, please do tell, i am very interested in different ways of solving this.

Comment: No problem friend. Wouldn't mind if you marked my reply as the answer if you feel that's what it is.

Comment: Oops sorry, was so happy forgot to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an example of `.each` with a delay using [jQuery’s `.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function:

```
$('#show-articles').click(function(event) {
  var delayInterval = 1;
  $('.articles').each(function(){
    $(this).delay(delayInterval * 50).fadeIn()
    delayInterval++;
  })
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

…of course you’ll need to adapt to your exact need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Jquery Delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)?